# Update manager for 14.04 tries to load updates 15.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, update-manager

I run 14.04 and recently downloaded an iso file of 15.04 to install for a friend. Since then, update Manager tries to install updates for 15.04 and tells me to insert a CD. How can I correct this? Thanks

Comment: list down the output of `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add a `#` at the beginning of the line, like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Alpha amd64 (20150316)]/ vivid main multiverse restricted universe
```